# Diamond Crystal - not geting output as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
row = int(input())
for i in range(1, row+1):
  for j in range(1,row-i+1):
    print(" ", end="")
  for j in range(1, 2*i):
    if j==1 or j==2*i-1:
      print("/", end="")
    else:
      print(" ", end="")
  print()


for i in range(row-1,0, -1):
  for j in range(1,row-i+1):
    print(" ", end="")
  for j in range(1, 2*i):
    if j==1 or j==2*i-1:
      print("/", end="")
    else:
      print(" ", end="")
  print()
```

In this python program it has two test cases, in this two test cases they were not getting expected output Please give me the code for expected output for two test cases. Thank you !

Question and test cases Url:-

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1sVH8M0vCCSky84V1PkWD-eKm1v0dPRC5/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=104486799211107564921&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: Please add the inputs as well as expected and actual outputs of your code to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
row = int(input())
print(" "*row+"/\\")
for i in range(1, row+1):
    print(" "*(row-i)+"/"+" "*2*i+"\\")
for i in range(row,0,-1):
    print(" "*(row-i)+"\\"+" "*2*i+"/")
print(" "*row+"\\/")
```

Output:

```
5
     /\
    /  \
   /    \
  /      \
 /        \
/          \
\          /
 \        /
  \      /
   \    /
    \  /
     \/
```